# how to replace placeholders with actual values with powershell

Tags: powershell

I just introduced to jdb and my mentor gave me next assignment:
I have one file with actual values src/main/resources/confing.properties
and placeholders like ${db1_password} in different classes.
How to replace placeholdes with actual values from properties file via PowerShell script?

```
db.host = jdbc:postgresql://localhost/school_db
db.login = tester
db.password = test
db.tables = src\\main\\resources\\tables_creation.sql
db.groups = 10
db.courses = 10
db.minimumStudentsInGroup = 10
db.maximumStudentsInGroup = 30
db.students = 200
db.maximumCoursesForStudent = 3
```

Comment: you should add a powershell tag

Comment: show an example of a placeholder please. and what is the purpose of the powershell script?

Comment: for now I use Properties class and use props.getProperty("db.tables") to get values from properties file, but it is not really safety to do it in this way.

Comment: Yes, but how is powershell relevant here, is your launch script in powershell? Then you can pass a variable to java using -Dvariablename=value on the commandline. Then use System.getProperty("variablename")